# getting an error of "RuntimeError at / There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'."

Tags: multithreading, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I found some older posts related here but they were too old to rely on. like
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727787/runtimeerror-there-is-no-current-event-loop-in-thread-in-async-apscheduler
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725890/runtimeerror-there-is-no-current-event-loop-in-thread-thread-1-multithreadi

I am pretty new to async functions.I had to fetch a pretty big data which was taking lot of time to load so had to switch over to async functions.My views.py looks somethings like this

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
       return await response


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
# Getter function with semaphore.
   async with sem:
      await fetch(url, session)


async def run(r):
  url = "http://myurl/{}"
  tasks = []
# create instance of Semaphore
  sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)

# Create client session that will ensure we dont open new connection
# per each request.
   async with ClientSession() as session:
      for i in range(0,r,10):
        # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
         task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url.format(i), session))
         tasks.append(task)

      responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
      await responses

number = 10000
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Comment: Are you running this inside ipython or a jupyter notebook?

Comment: I am running it in a django app