# ERROR:root:Error in xyz There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-7'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, async-await, python-asyncio, fire-and-forget

I am trying to achieve fire_and_forget functionality and here are the details.

Async decorater i am trying to use:

```
import asyncio
import time


def fire_and_forget(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, *kwargs)

    return wrapped
```

My Async call using above decorator:

```
@fire_and_forget
def call_async(self, req, body, headers_params):
    logger.info("Calling ASYNC")
    try:
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        response = f.read()
        f.close()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("api exception %s" % e)
        return None

    # Parse and return the response
    try:
        res = self._parse_response(response)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Exception in parsing response of %s" % e)
        res = None
    logger.debug("clevertap response: {}".format(res))
```

My Flask app calling test_xyz which in turns fire the above fire and forget call_async:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from call_xyz import test_xyz

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/events_dm')
def events_dm():
    session_id = request.args.get('sessionId', "11111111")
    test_obj = test_xyz(session_id)
    test_obj.track_test()
    return jsonify({"success": True})


app.run(
            host='0.0.0.0',
            port=8091,
            debug=True,
            threaded=True
        )
```

I am not able to understand where to set my event loop correctly so that i don't get the error: "Error in xyz There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-7'" and my events get fired correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Flask is not asyncio-compatible, so you shouldn't attempt to use asyncio within it.

Besides, you're not actually using asyncio's functionality, but `run_in_executor` which calls into `concurrent.futures`, i.e. uses threads under the hood. If that's what you need, you can create an executor directly and just submit your function to it. For example:

```
import concurrent.futures
_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

def fire_and_forget(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return _pool.submit(lambda: f(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapped
```

Answer (score 0):

You must probably go through once `asyncio` usage and its main heart `event loop` understanding.

[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727787/runtimeerror-there-is-no-current-event-loop-in-thread-in-async-apscheduler) which might help you to understand.

Here is the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xbl7XjFYsN4&t=7s) with some good explanation

Just give some flow for how use `coroutine` with normal `Flask` app here is the sample one.

```
import asyncio
import datetime

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request


app = Flask(__name__)

def print_now():
    print(datetime.datetime.now())


async def keep_printing(name: str="") -> None:
    print(name, end=" ")
    print_now()
    await asyncio.sleep(1.50)


async def main(num_times):
    result = await asyncio.gather(
        keep_printing("first"),
        keep_printing("second"),
        keep_printing("third"),
    )
    return result


def execute_statement():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(main(2))
    loop.close()


@app.route('/events_dm')
def events_dm():
    execute_statement()
    return jsonify({"success": True})

app.run(
            host='0.0.0.0',
            port=8091,
            debug=True,
            threaded=True
        )
```

Output when you hit `/events_dm`

```
first 2020-07-18 00:46:26.452921
second 2020-07-18 00:46:26.452921
third 2020-07-18 00:46:26.452921
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2020 00:46:27] "GET /events_dm HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```