# When to use asyncio.get_running_loop() vs asyncio.get_event_loop()?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have seen running a blocking code using

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
await loop.run_in_executor(None, blockingfunc)
```

And

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
await loop.run_in_executor(None, blockingfunc)
```

When should we use `asyncio.get_running_loop()` vs `asyncio.get_event_loop()`?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html), `get_running_loop` will raise a `RuntimeError` is no loop is running; `get_event_loop`, on the other hand, will create one.

Answer (score 13):

In accordance with the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html), both the `get_running_loop` and `get_event_loop` are used to actually get an active loop, with the difference that the latter `get_event_loop` has more complex behaviour, thus `get_running_loop` can be used widely in the applications, where the existance of the loop is not questionable.

Moreover, in the documentation it is suggested to used `run` method to obtain an event loop (available starting from the Python 3.7 version), e.g.

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('hello')

asyncio.run(main())
```

instead of:

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('hello')
        
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(main)
loop.run_forever()
```

Please note, that the `run` method solution can work weirdly in Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 4):

**`asyncio.get_event_loop()`** has the caracteristics of **`asyncio.get_running_loop()`**, **`asyncio.new_event_loop()`** and **`asyncio.set_event_loop()`**.

**[asyncio.get_event_loop()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) deprecated since version 3.10**:

> Get the current event loop.
>
> If there is no current event loop set in the current OS thread, the OS
> thread is main, and set_event_loop() has not yet been called, asyncio
> will create a new event loop and set it as the current one.

[**asyncio.get_running_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop):

> Return the running event loop in the current OS thread.

[**asyncio.new_event_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.new_event_loop):

> Create and return a new event loop object.

[**asyncio.set_event_loop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.set_event_loop):

> Set loop as a current event loop for the current OS thread

For example, if running this code below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    while True:
        print("Test")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def call_test():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(test())

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.create_task(call_test())
loop.run_forever()
```

**`Test`** is printed every second:

```
Test
Test
Test
...
```

So now, we can replace **`asyncio.get_running_loop()`** with **`asyncio.get_event_loop()`** in **`call_test()`** and replace **`loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()`** and **`asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)`** with **`asyncio.get_event_loop()`** as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    while True:
        print("Test")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def call_test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Here
    # loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(test())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Here
# loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
# asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.create_task(call_test())
loop.run_forever()
```

Then, **`Test`** is still printed every second:

```
Test
Test
Test
...
```

So, about when to use **`asyncio.get_event_loop()`** or **`asyncio.get_running_loop()`**, you shouldn't use **`asyncio.get_event_loop()`** anytime because it is **deprecated since version 3.10**. So instead, you should use **`asyncio.get_running_loop()`** everytime and also **`asyncio.new_event_loop()`** and **`asyncio.set_event_loop()`**. But if you really want to use **`asyncio.get_event_loop()`**, use it to decrease code.

Comment: You state that get_event_loop is deprecated since Python 3.10, and I have seen that in a blog post as well, but that's actually not true.  The function itself is not deprecated, but it will log a deprecation warning in certain scenarios, when no loop is running.

It's actually still necessary to use this, instead of get_running_loop, in cases outside of a co-routine or callback, since you are never in a running loop.  From there, get_running_loop will always raise an error, but get_event_loop will work correctly.