# How to replace asyncio.get_event_loop() to avoid the DeprecationWarning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

The code below works, but I'm a bit confused by the:

```
DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

and the

```
DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coroutine_list))
```

warnings.

I've found [this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/212#issuecomment-841992444) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73367187/1501285) but what I'm confused about is how to update my code. I understand that there isn't an even loop yet, but how do I set it? I assumed that I needed to change `asyncio.get_event_loop()` with `asyncio.new_event_loop()` but this doesn't seem to work.

This is my code

```
async def flush(self, queue_c) -> None:
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        result_objects_action = loop.run_in_executor(None, self.create_objects, queue_c)
        # do stuff
    except:
        # except handling

def _run_queue(self) -> None:
    coroutine_list = []
    c = 0
    while c < len(self._queue):
        coroutine_list.append(self.flush(c))
        c+=1
    # What should be changed here?
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coroutine_list))
    self._queue = []
```

Comment: The preferred way to start a new loop in `asyncio.run`, though you can't pass `asyncio.gather` to it directly, you'd need to create a separate coroutine to wrap it. `async def main` is a common pattern for that.

Answer (score 5):

Calling *asyncio.new_event_loop()* isn't enough, you need to set it after with *asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)*. This deprecation warning for *get_event_loop()* was introduced by python 3.10 i believe. Here's how i setup the event loop so that it works with any python 3.x version:

```py
import sys
import asyncio

if sys.version_info < (3, 10):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
else:
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

Comment: You can shorten the version check to `sys.version_info < (3, 10)`.

Comment: Why can't you just do `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop; asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)`?  That will work with all versions, I think.  You would only do this if, for some reason, you can't use the simpler asyncio.run(coro) approach.