# How do versions after py3.10 implement asyncio.get_event_loop with the same behavior as previous versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, sanic

[python3.10-asyncio-get_event_loop](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=get_event_loop#asyncio.get_event_loop)

Deprecated since version 3.10: Emits a deprecation warning if there is no running event loop. In future Python releases, this function may become an alias of get_running_loop() and will accordingly raise a RuntimeError if there is no running event loop.

The behavior of get_event_loop has changed in version 3.10, now the sanic-jwt library needs to be compatible with later versions of 3.10, and needs to be modified to remove this warning(DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop)

The place of the warning is the **call** method under ConfigItem on line 134
[sanic_jwt/configuration.py](https://github.com/ahopkins/sanic-jwt/blob/main/sanic_jwt/configuration.py)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AI9l.png)

I tried the method of this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73361664/asyncio-get-event-loop-deprecationwarning-there-is-no-current-event-loop) and the test did not pass. It should not match the behavior of the version before 3.10

[PR](https://github.com/ahopkins/sanic-jwt/pull/236)

Comment: I need a function for py3.10 get_event_loop that behaves the same way as get_event_loop before 3.10

Answer (score 0):

If you want to patch the library, you could replace line 134:

```
if asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running():
    # some code
```

with:

```
try:
    asyncio.get_running_loop()
except RuntimeError:
    pass
else:
    # some code
```

That should work with all versions of Python.