# Use pycord to make a music bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

My English is not good, I am still a newcomer, please forgive me if the question is not good.
I'm using PyCord 2.3.2 to make a discord music robot. Currently, I only do the join command. Although I can join the channel, it throws an error.

```
Ignoring exception in command join:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 178, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\BOT\Cogs\Music.py", line 52, in join
    await channel.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1932, in connect
    await voice.connect(timeout=timeout, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 404, in connect
    self.ws = await self.connect_websocket()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 375, in connect_websocket
    await ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 944, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(utils._from_json(msg.data))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 861, in received_message
    await self.initial_connection(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 898, in initial_connection
    recv = await self.loop.sock_recv(state.socket, 70)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 696, in sock_recv
    return await self._proactor.recv(sock, n)
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='pycord: on_message' coro=<Client._run_event() running at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:377>> got Future <_OverlappedFuture pending overlapped=<pending, 0x183de095fc0>> attached to a different loop

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 950, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 187, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='pycord: on_message' coro=<Client._run_event() running at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:377>> got Future <_OverlappedFuture pending overlapped=<pending, 0x183de095fc0>> attached to a different loop
```

I tried to find the problem according to the error, but there is no good solution, hope to find a solution here.

this is my program
Cogs:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
import os
import youtube_dl
import asyncio
from definition.Classes import Cog_Extension

class Music(Cog_Extension):
    @commands.command(name='join', help='Tells the bot to join the voice channel')
    async def join(self,ctx):
        if not ctx.message.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("{} is not connected to a voice channel".format(ctx.message.author.name))
            return
        else:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

Bot:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json

with open("config.json" , "r" ,encoding="utf8") as configFiles:  
    config = json.load(configFiles)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config["command_prefix"], intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    os.system('clear')
    print("-"*15)
    print("bot online")
    print("-"*15)
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print(bot.user)
    print("-"*15)
    Activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching,name="bot")
    await bot.change_presence(activity=Activity)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)


async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./Cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            try:
                bot.load_extension(f'Cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
                print(f'✅   load {filename}')
            except Exception as error:
                print(f'❎   {filename} error  {error}')


async def main():
    await load()
    await bot.start(config["Token"])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Is there any more code? I'm assuming there is. You've imported `asyncio` and the error seems related as it's complaining about running in a different loop.

Comment: @ESloman
I'll add a bot's main program to see how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could simplify your code a bit and that'll likely help:

```py
def load():
    # doesn't need to be async
    for filename in os.listdir('./Cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            try:
                bot.load_extension(f'Cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
                print(f'✅   load {filename}')
            except Exception as error:
                print(f'❎   {filename} error  {error}')

load()
bot.run(config["Token"])
```

Or, if you really want to use [`bot.start`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/clients.html#discord.Bot.run) then the docs recommend doing it this way:

```py
def load():
    # still doesn't need to be async
    for filename in os.listdir('./Cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            try:
                bot.load_extension(f'Cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
                print(f'✅   load {filename}')
            except Exception as error:
                print(f'❎   {filename} error  {error}')

load()

# for python3.11
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
# loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(bot.start(config["Token"]))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.run_until_complete(close())
    # cancel all tasks lingering
finally:
    loop.close()
```

I used the latter method, and copied your cog and my bot joined the VC I was in without any issues.

Comment: Thank you, this successfully solved my problem, but after using your code it throws a message like this
C:\Users\user\Desktop\BOT\Bot.py:110: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
   loop = asyncio. get_event_loop(),What does this mean

Comment: That's an error when there's no loop running. I added an edit that would resolve that. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73361664/asyncio-get-event-loop-deprecationwarning-there-is-no-current-event-loop