# Pytest a function which invokes asyncio coroutines

Tags: python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I am trying to write a unit testcase using mock and pytest-asyncio. I have a normal function launching an asyncio coroutine using `asyncio.run`. [Using python3.7]

```
import asyncio

async def sample_async(arg2):
     # do something
     proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(arg2)
     # some more asyncio calls
     rc = proc.returncode
     return rc

def launcher(arg1, arg2):
    if arg1 == "no_asyncio":
        # do something
        print("No asyncio")
        return 0
    else:
        return_code = asyncio.run(sample_async(arg2))
        # do something
        return return_code
```

I was able to write unittest for the asyncio function `sample_async` but not for `launcher`. Here is what I have tried:

```
class AsyncMock(MagicMock):
    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AsyncMock, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)


@patch("asyncio.create_subprocess_shell", new_callable=AsyncMock)
def test_launcher(async_shell):
    arg1 = "async"
    arg2 = "/bin/bash ls"
    sample.launcher(arg1, arg2)
    async_shell.assert_called_once()
```

When I try to run the pytest, I keep getting `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.` I can't use `@pytest.mark.asyncio` for this test as the function `launcher` is not an asyncio coroutine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

See here about explicitly creating an event loop:

[RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread in async + apscheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727787/runtimeerror-there-is-no-current-event-loop-in-thread-in-async-apscheduler)

See the documentation for get_event_loop() in particular here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html

> If there is no current event loop set in the current OS thread, the OS thread is main, and set_event_loop() has not yet been called, asyncio will create a new event loop and set it as the current one.

Likely, because your OS thread is not main, you need to do some manual init'ing of the loop. Make sure you have a clear mental picture of the event loop and what these functions do in its lifecycle, think of the loop as nothing more than an object with methods and other objects (tasks) it works on. As the docs say, the main OS thread does some "magic" for you that isn't really magic just "behind the scenes".